# See version of Operating System in shell unix

Tags: linux, shell, operating-system, fedora, lsb

How can I see in the shell unix the version and the operating system that the machine have?

I try the command lsb_release but i can't see with that.

Any solution?

Comment: The best answer depends on which operating system you have!

Comment: isn´t it `lsb_release -a` ?

Comment: What's wrong with uname -o?  Unless by "operating system" you mean "distribution".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Linux you can see

> cat /etc/fedora-release

This way you just can know the version if you known the distribution in this case Fedora.
but you can always try for a file *-release in the folder /etc

Comment: just tried this on Ubuntu and got the correct information: `cat /etc/*-release`

Answer (score 4):

You tagged your question with Ubuntu, so here is a solution for Ubuntu:

`lsb_release -a` will give you the version of Ubuntu installed.

If you are unsure if it is 32 or 64 bit you can call `file /sbin/init`.

The kernel version used is shown when running `uname -a`

Comment: Sorry, i change that, is fedora.

But uname -a is good too, for the kernel version.